# Get institutional holdings of stocks programmatically

Tags: equities, programming

First of, I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but a search on Google for another programmatically related question regarding stocks led me here, so here it goes.

Is there any way to programmatically get a list of the institutional owners of stocks traded on (primarily, other exchanges are also of interest) Nasdaq? And in case my financial vocabulary isn't up to par, the list I'm looking for is one like [this](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/achc/institutional-holdings).

Edit: To clarify, I'm not interested in reading the data from the web page. I'm curious if there are any FTP, API or other sort of service offering the data in such a way that it's easy to get and assimilate for a computer program. Parsing the data on a web page is kind of a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: Either you find a different data source that can provide APIs/structured data (which is usually not free) or do some web-scraping (which may have legal or moral issues). For web-scraping techniques it's probably better to search/ask in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Those institutional holdings are reported to the SEC, I believe.  Therefore it seems likely somebody has it available in a nice format, but like you I don't know who.

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspects maintain lists  for each stock.  Bloomberg for instance has `OWN<GO>` and `HLDS<GO>` but in those cases you need to iterate through each stock individually.  These are done on a best efforts basis.

I'm pretty sure this is a design choice to keep you using the terminal front end and not the api.

Other than that, you are going to be left with writing a web spider.